# Can .ogg video play in mobile device

Tags: html, node.js, video-streaming, ogg

Right now I am making a server where it displays a video with HTML. I have tried using the .`.mp4`and `.ogg` video for my computer and it worked perfectly. But when I tried to use a mobile device, only the `.mp4` displayed, and the `.ogg` did not. Can mobile devices not display `.ogg` video files?

Comment: Improved English for clarity.

Comment: Proper compatibility chart here:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.ogg video can't be played in both iOS and android
https://caniuse.com/#feat=ogv